# How to find the volume of partially-filled spherical cap?

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, spheres

I have a water tank, a horizontally placed cylinder with two ends (one at right, the other at the left), these ends have a spherical cap [not hemispherical] of a sphere whose radius is $R$.

Given $L$, the level of water from ground (as in figure), and $W$, the width (i.e. the distance between the top of the spherical cap to its circular base)...
I can find the volume of partially-filled cylinder or the cap (but filled not partially filled).
Can anyone help me?

[image: A cylindrical tank with non-hemispherical end caps]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Thoughtful questions, even homework-related, are welcome. However, you should not expect others to do your homework for you, and it's inappropriate to post your homework verbatim. (That may not be what you're doing, but all people here can go by is appearances. I expect that's why your question has gotten downvoted.) Instead, please try to ask questions about specific places where you're stuck, or about particular concepts you don't understand.
Here, could you please give some context? Particularly, do you know single- or multi-variable calculus? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I know about them... my problem is only, the limits to that shape before I integrate... I can find using integral the volume of the cap but full filled not partially filled, so if there is no level of water... I can find the volume easy with integral

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions: A ball of radius $R$ centered at the origin is described by
$$
x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} \leq R^{2}.
\tag{1}
$$
The end cap of your tank can be modeled as the set of points
$$
x_{0} := R - W \leq x \leq R.
\tag{2}
$$
Taking the positive $z$-axis to point "upward" (perpendicularly to the fluid surface), the bottom of the tank lies at height
$$
z_{0} := -\sqrt{R^{2} - x_{0}^{2}} = -\sqrt{(2R - W)W}.
$$
The fluid in the tank therefore lies in the region
$$
z_{0} \leq z \leq z_{0} + L.
\tag{3}
$$
The proposed strategy is to cut the region into slices $x = \text{constant}$ and calculate the area of a slice, then integrate the areas from $x = x_{0} = R - W$ to $x = R$, see (2). The slice at $x$ is the portion of a disk of radius $\sqrt{R^{2} - x^{2}}$ cut by a chord lying at a distance $|z_{0} + L|$ from the center.

Overall, the calculation looks messy but doable. I haven't worked out the details, however, and I haven't given much thought to other coordinate systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is one relatively straightforward thing to try:
the surface area of the water in the tank is the rate of change
of the volume as the depth of the water increases.

Write an expression showing the surface area of the water as a
function of the depth of the water.
Then integrate over the appropriate interval
(from no water in the tank up to the given level).